# F# JsonProvider type fails to parse decimal

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

Why can't `someJsonType` parse `9.433536880271462E-4` to decimal?

Parsing the value myself works fine `let c = decimal "9.433536880271462E-4"`

```
#r "nuget: FSharp.Data, 3.3.3"
type someJsonType = FSharp.Data.JsonProvider<"""
{
  "point": 45.5
}
""">
let a = someJsonType.Parse "{ \"point\": 12.5 }"
let b = someJsonType.Parse "{ \"point\": 9.433536880271462E-4 }"
let c = someJsonType.Parse "{ \"point\": 0.0009433536880271462 }"
printfn "%f" a.Point // OK
printfn "%f" b.Point // exception
printfn "%f" c.Point // OK
let d = decimal "9.433536880271462E-4" // OK
```

Exception:

```
System.Exception: Expecting a Decimal at '/point', got 0.0009433536880271462
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfModule.PrintFormatToStringThenFail@1433.Invoke(String message) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\printf.fs:line 1433
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.DispatchTailCalls(IntPtr callersRetAddrSlot, IntPtr callTarget, IntPtr retVal)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.OptimizedClosures.Invoke@3298-1.Invoke(T2 u, T3 v) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\prim-types.fs:line 3298
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0072>.$FSI_0072.main@()
Stopped due to error
```

Comment: What version of F# Data are you using? I tried this with an old one that I had just opened in my Visual Studio and it worked fine.. but it was using an old version...

Comment: Why aren't the two values parsed in quotes? What is the types of a and b? Could it be a problem with the decimal separator? Comma needed?

Comment: @TomasPetricek added `Fsharp.Data` version to sample

Comment: @BentTranberg The quotes were a mistake - removed them. When using `,` instead of `.` the json becomes invalid. `a` and `b` are of type `JsonProvider<...>.Root`

Comment: Found this open issue : https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data/issues/1230

Comment: And I get that error with the latest stable 4.0.1. There's no later prerelease on NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

The data type is inferred as `decimal`, but b is `float` hence the exception.  This is a quirk that means you have to modify the sample json to ensure the correct type is inferred. So, if you want to infer `float` then you have to modify your sample:

```
#r "nuget: FSharp.Data, 3.3.3"
type someJsonType = FSharp.Data.JsonProvider<"""
{
  "point": 9.433536880271462E-4
}
""">
let a = someJsonType.Parse "{ \"point\": 12.5 }"
let b = someJsonType.Parse "{ \"point\": 9.433536880271462E-4 }"
let c = someJsonType.Parse "{ \"point\": 0.0009433536880271462 }"
printfn "%f" a.Point // val a.Point is float with get
printfn "%f" b.Point // OK
printfn "%f" c.Point // OK
```

*If you want it to be `decimal` you can cast this after loading json data into your local object.* This is what you are actually doing with `let d = decimal "9.433536880271462E-4" // OK`

(Similarly if the json schema is meant to be providing floats or decimals but the sample only has what appears to be an int, an int would be inferred, so again you have to modify the sample to ensure the correct type is inferred)

The JsonProvider can only work with what is at hand in the sample json, hence the importance of the sample helping the inference.

(Note: We don't always have control of the sample json, if coming from a live third party site, so I think some form of type annotation might be useful to assist but as far as I know this does not exist yet.)

Comment: What should I do if the types needs to be `decimal` as I can not lose precision?

Comment: For sure, that is general issue except you have as much precision as provided in the Json data and so  there should be no loss in this scenario unless you can show a counter-example?